# How to use android paste option

Tags: java, android, webview

I wrote an android application which loads a form in webview and it allows user to scan a barcode and copy the result of the barcode in the clipboard. I want to paste that from clipboard to the webview using android's paste function. When I try to search for paste it just shows me to get the data from clipboard and put it in an EditText field, But that's not what I want. I want to use the stock paste function (similar to longpress the field -> paste) in my code. Thanks

```
public void clickScan(View view){

    final Activity activity = this;
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan the serial number");
    integrator.setCameraId(0);
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents() ==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Scanning the code. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            String input =  result.getContents().toString();
            ((ClipboardManager)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)).setText(input);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), input,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String str = "test";
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSesTx1IBlPZlN5RXzzauJWYxStHOqt7wH_z4lFe0JHQmKm91w/viewform?usp=sf_link");



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer guys. 
I used:-

```
webView.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PASTE));
```

Thanks.